# What is the difference between a daemon and a server process?

Tags: server, services

Definition of `server` from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)):

> A server is a piece of computer hardware or software (computer program) that provides functionality for other programs or devices, called "clients".

Definition of `daemon` from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)):

> ... is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user. ... Systems often start daemons at boot time which will respond to network requests, hardware activity, or other programs by performing some task.

From what I understand with the above definitions is that both `server` (from a software perspective) and `daemon` are programs running continuously which will respond to a request.

If so, the terms look interchangeable to me. Is that so? If not, what differentiates a `daemon` and a `server` ?

Comment: @Hugo I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to move the question to Server Fault. If any moderator could move it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Hugo I think this question would be closed as off-topic on Server Fault; their scope is rather precise. It's a perfectly fine question here and should not be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A server does things on request (SSH connection, FTP/HTTP requests...).

By contrast a daemon has a life of its own, and responds to system events or to periodic actions. For instance the `fail2ban` daemon periodically looks for brute-force attempts in login logs and bans the corresponding addresses. Other daemons manage logs (truncate/compress) or the network connections (NetworkManager)...

Comment: would you say it's roughly equivalent to: `daemon` = `server` + `cron` ?

Comment: No because some daemons react to non-cron events such as plugging in some USB device. And cron itself is a daemon.

Answer (score 4):

`Server` this concept refers to a type of program, a server is a program that works to serve someone, to serve another program - a client (the webserver serves requests from browsers, the mail server receives and sends emails from mail clients).

`Daemon` is the mode of operation of a program, which implies that the program is running in the background.

The server can support the daemon mode, but it can also support running in the foreground.